# CSS Container Width

Tags: css, grid

If you do the math, the container is 946px / 5 (columns) = 189.2px. I don't see how they have managed to fit five columns in without extra space left over? Can be viewed [here](http://www.tesco.com/direct/home-electrical/vacuums-steam-cleaners/cat3376647.cat?icid=homeelectrical_navstamp_slot1) (1200px view).

[image: Container]

[image: Coulmn]

Comment: The calculation is correct, where is the problem?

Comment: @emmanuel 189px (width of column) * 5 = 945, however the container is 946px wide.

Comment: Include border of 1px that comes out to total of 946

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their wrapper element, `ul.products` actually only has a width of `945px`, plus `1px` border left (and top). That's why their five columns with each a width of `189px` add up with no space.

Answer (score 1):

This is the layout:

[image: screen shot]

1px left border.  This is the CSS:

```
border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
```